# My site doesn't have a SSL certificate, but Google is indexing the HTTPS version

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, https, http

Redirecting to HTTPS causes an error, Google should be indexing the HTTP version. How can I enforce that? I have no forms or logins on my website, I have no SSL certificate.

For example: Searching for `paul and martin consultancy` in Google returns the home page (second result) with an `https://` protocol:

[image: Google search returns HTTPS in link]

And clicking this link naturally results in the following browser error:

[image: Your connection is not private browser warning]

I am using this `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works just fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/RCfVt If it's not for you, then you have something hijacking on your browser or the DNS cache needs refreshing.

Comment: And I tested with www., without www and even using `site:`.  My advice... clear your DNS in browser, in the operating system and your router.

Comment: @SimonHayter "works just fine" - But you're not following the example stated by the OP. I'm able to reproduce the same results (added screenshot to the question). And a `site:` search (without www) also produces similar results. This has nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: It is probably easier at this point to just add the certificate and make it work. You should go SSL anyway and the URL is seemingly out there in the wild already.